# Javascript apply() arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, prototype

How comes this code :

```
function a() {
  console.log('a', arguments);
  b.apply(null, arguments);
}
function b() {
  console.log('b', arguments);
}

a('foo', 'bar');
b.apply(null, { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' });
```

outputs :

```
a { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }
b { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }
b {}
```

instead of :

```
a { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }
b { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }
b { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }
```

The **arguments** variable in function **a** is identical to the object **{ '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }**.

Any clues ?

Comment: @user2864740: He isn't using it as a variable name.

Comment: @user2864740: No; he's asking why his fake arguments object in the last line (which doesn't have `length`) doesn't work.

Comment: So back to the stated assertion of 'being identical': it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply()` accepts an array-like object.

You need to either pass an array or set `length`.

Comment: Ok it works with length but I didnt set it when I called **b.apply(null, arguments);** within **a**.
How does it work ?

Comment: arguments is already an array-like object so you didn't need to